# sql insert only two values into a table with 10 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has 10 fields: field1, field2,..., field10

Now suppose i only want to insert values into first two columns, and put '' on the rest.

I'm currently using

```
     insert into table1 values
  (100,200,'','','','','','','','','','')
```

I wonder if there is a better way to avoid ,'','','',''  ?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just specify the fields you want to add like this:

```
insert into table1 (field1, field2) VALUES (100,200)
```

In this case field1 will insert 100, and field2 will insert 200.

The other fields in your table will be null, so you need to make sure that is allowed.

EDIT:

in the comments, @andreas is correct - any field you don't specify will be given it's default value (which may be null)

Comment: Providing an explanation is more important than giving the resulting code.

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column
I got this error, i guess because my columns don't allow for null?

Comment: They should have a default value - does not have to be null.

Comment: @user3344443 So you don't allow NULL but you allow an empty space? If you consider those the same thing, you should choose one or the other.

Comment: yes, I allow '', i guess i need to set default('') first?